# How can I get jQuery DataTables to sort on hidden value, but search on displayed value?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

I have a simple DataTables grid which contains date columns. I have provided two values for the date in my JSON data set, one for display and one specifically designed so that DataTables can sort it. My web application allows users to choose a bunch of different date formats, so it needs to be flexible.

This is my JSON data that DataTables gets from from the web server via `sAjaxSource`.

```
{
  Reports : [
    { Date: { Sort = "20101131133000", Display : "11/31/2010 1:30 PM" } }, 
    { Date: { Sort = "20100912120000", Display : "1200 EST 2010-09-12" } }, 
  ]
}
```

It is easy to tell DataTables to sort based on the `Date.SortValue` property and to make the `Display` property visible to the user by using `fnRender()`. So this gets me halfway to my goal.

```
var dataTableConfig = {
  sAjaxSource: "/getreports",
  sAjaxDataProp: "Reports",
  aoColumns: [
    { mDataProp: "User" },
    { mDataProp: "Date.Sort", 
      bSortable: true, 
      sName: "Date", 
      bUseRendered: false, 
      fnRender: function (oObj) {
        return oObj.aData[oObj.oSettings.aoColumns[oObj.iDataColumn].sName].Display;
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

***Here's my problem.*** I want to allow the user to enter a filter (using the built-in filter input that DataTables provides) based on the displayed value, but they cannot.

For example. If a user entered "EST", they would get zero results because datatables filters based on the value specified in `mDataProp` not based on the value returned from `fnRender`.

Can anyone help me figure out how to sort AND filter a date column? Thanks.

Comment: The correct answer to this question has changed since datatables has been updated. I'm not sure what SO policy is on changing the accepted answer vs getting the answer updated but one or the other would be handy perhaps?

Comment: I am happy to change the accepted answer. I don't use DataTables any longer, can you advise on which one is better?

Comment: CW Spear's answer marked `Nov 5 '13 at 7:12` appears to be correct, and worked for me.

Comment: @jessegavin wjat are you using?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is an old post, but hopefully this will help someone else that comes here.

In a more recent version of DataTables, `bUseRendered` and `fnRender` are deprecated.

[`mRender`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) is the new way of doing this sort of thing and has a slightly different approach.

You can solve your issue with something along the lines of:

```
...
{ mDataProp: "Date.Sort"
  bSortable: true, 
  sName: "Date", 
  // this will return the Display value for everything
  // except for when it's used for sorting,
  // which then it will use the Sort value
  mRender: function (data, type, full) {
    if(type == 'sort') return data.Sort;
    return data.Display
  }
}
...
```

Comment: Confirmed.  This works.  **The type call data requested - this will be 'filter', 'display', 'type' or 'sort'.**  Does anyone even use datatables any more?

Comment: The accepted answer is now wrong because `iDataSort` is deprecated, making this answer correct.

Comment: @Sebastianb, I have used data tables for some time now.  I was confused because all of the old datatables property names are all in Hungarian notation.  In one release of datatables the Hungarian notation was dropped.  All of this older documentation makes it very confusing.

Answer (score 85):

I believe the existing answers are deprecated due to updates to DataTables.  HTML5 supports attributes that DataTables can use to easily sort columns.  Specifically the `data-sort` attribute.  (See https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html)

I can easily sort tables like so:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Age</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John Doe</td>
      <td data-sort="37">2/1/78 (37 years old)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jane Doe</td>
      <td data-sort="35">12/1/80 (35 years old)</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

It doesn't matter that the 'Age' column contains numbers, symbols, and letters, DataTables will sort using the 'data-sort' attribute.

Comment: Works great, but with version 1.10.4, I had an issue if the first row has an empty data-sort value: it won't use the attribute from other rows. So make sure you never output `data-sort=""` in you html.

Comment: It should be noted that this solution does not work if you're populating the table with Ajax/json.

Comment: Oh my god, this helped me so much after trying so many dumb hacks. Smart and easy. Thank you!

Comment: it's a best solution for all. Thanks

Comment: thank you, this solved my problem when i had multiple dates on same td

Answer (score 20):

Try a little bit different approach:

Put both columns in the table (I will call them DateDisplay and DateSort), do not use render function and just hide the DateSort column. Then in the aoColumns array for the column DateDisplay put `{ "iDataSort": 2 }`, where 2 is an index of the DateSort column.

In this case, DateDisplay column will be shown in original data, and filter will be done by this column, but sorting will be done by the values in the DateSort column.

There are more details about the iDataSort property on the datatables site or in the http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/JQuery-DataTables.aspx section"Configure sorting".

Comment: @CWSpear's answer is easier to implement I think.

Comment: This answer applies to legacy datatables and is now deprecated

Answer (score 19):

Umm...instead of going through all of this rigmarole just add a hidden `span` with your "Sort By" to the front:

```
<td><span style="display:none;">20101131133000</span>11/31/2010 1:30 PM</td>
```

**Note**: This does mean that they can search by either the hidden or shown value...this may be a consequence you can't live with.

Comment: I really like this solution to the problem.

Comment: Genius !  You just saved me a lot of work!  Although I was already thinking along those lines, and I tried an html comment <!-- sortvalue  --> - your method worked.

Answer (score 11):

+1 JocaPC

I'd like to add to JocaPC's answer by reminding everyone that javascript utilizes zero-indexed arrays.

Example:

```
HiddenSortString (0) | Date (1)                   | Some Text (2)
...................................................................
1349035566           | September 30, 2012 2:06 pm | blah blah
1349118137           | October 01, 2012 1:02 pm   | blah blah
1349371297           | October 04, 2012 11:21 am  | blah blah
...................................................................
```

To sort the date field using the hidden string you would use the following.

```
$('.mytable').dataTable({
    "aoColumns": [{"bVisible": false},{"iDataSort": 0},null]
});
```

Comment: Thanks JakeJ ... +1 to CWSpear for cleaning up the example.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `data-sort` attribute on the td, like

```
<td data-sort="12342345434">Thursday, May 9th 11</td>
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you already have your data in sortable and displayable format, this is all code you need.

It will use `Date.Sort` for sorting and `Date.Display` for visuals. This is documented [here](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data#Predefined-values).

```
columns: [{
    data: 'Date',
    render: {
        _:   'Display',
        sort: 'Sort'
    }
}]
```

Answer (score 3):

For those using an ajax data source you can use *[Orthogonal data](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data)*.  For instance, in your ajax response return one of your columns as an object with a display value and a sort value (similar to what the OP did):

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "customer":"JOHN DOE",
         "rating":{
            "display": "★★★",
            "sort":"3"
         },
      },
      {
         "customer":"BILLY NOAH",
         "rating":{
            "display": "★★★★★",
            "sort":"5"
         },
      }
   ]
}
```

Now in your table options you can use `columns()` like this:

```
"columns" : [
   {
      "data":"customer"
   },
   {
      "data":"rating",
      "render":{
         "_":"display",
         "sort":"sort"
      }
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to sort column by a hidden column (Sort). To to this you have to include a column that contains the sort data, hide the column and sort the Display Column by the hidden column.

```
   "aoColumnDefs:[
    {"sTitle": "Display", "iDataSort":1, "aTargets":[2]},
    {"bVisible": false, "aTargets":[2]}
    ], 

aoColumns: [
    { mData: "User" },
    { mData: "Display"},
    { mData: "Sort"}
  ]
```