# How to call javascript on pagination and record select of Datatables?

Tags: jquery, pagination, datatables, raty

I'm using [Datatables](http://www.datatables.net/) to show data in tabular form. I'm using [jQuery Raty library](http://wbotelhos.com/raty/) to show 5 stars in a column.

The problem is: on the first page, the Raty library works (as the DOM element is present), but when I paginate, sort or select page size in Datatables, new records come into the picture which were not there previously & Raty is not implicitly working.

I need to call Raty again on pagination, sort etc. How can I do that?
Is there a better way to solve this issue?

Please help & guide.

EDIT:

This is my datatable init:

```
$('#mydatatable').dataTable({
            "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
            "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
            "oLanguage": {
                "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page",
                "oPaginate": {
                    "sPrevious": "Prev",
                    "sNext": "Next"
                }
            }
        });
```

While the Raty lib init is as follows:

```
$('.star').raty({ 
                readOnly: true,
                score: 3.26
                });
```

In the HTML markup, the raty column looks like:

```
<td><div class="star" ></div></td>
```

where  is just another column in Datatables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could try the [fnDrawCallback](http://datatables.net/usage/callbacks) in datatables? See it in use here: http://live.datatables.net/#preview

Although, that occurs on every keyup during search, which could make your app slower.

i.e.

```
$('#mydatatable').dataTable({
    "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
        "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
        "oLanguage": {
        "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page",
            "oPaginate": {
            "sPrevious": "Prev",
                "sNext": "Next"
        }
    },
        "fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {
// I would suggest adding some code here to conditionally check if it hasn't already
// been initialised on a particular .star element
        $('.star').raty({
            readOnly: true,
            score: 3.26
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Let me try that & get back to you.

Comment: That works like a charm. Thank you so much for the quick resolution. Saved me a lot of headache. :)

Comment: No problem! I just added a note to my answer - I would suggest trying to wrap the raty init in fnDrawCallback in some conditional check to see whether it has/hasn't been initialised on a particular instance of `.star`... e.g. if raty adds a class, maybe you could do `.star[class!=some_raty_class]` just to prevent it from re-initialising it one one row that already has it (in the case of filtering results) (or the plugin may even just do that by itself!)

Comment: You're correct. I'll add some code to check it & will init only if it hasn't been init before. Gotit! Awesome. 1 more thing, is it possible to attach integer values to elements in datatables, e.g. in this case I'm showing stars, but i would like to sort it on the basis of stars. Like 5 highest, 1 lowest...how can I do that in this scenario?

Comment: Yes there is, although you have to either make a custom function for it, or if you can dump the rating into the markup when you generate the table, that would work using the " Hidden title numeric sorting " option (http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting#functions_data_source) you would have to add that code to your script file.

Comment: Yeah, thanks , got the idea from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668047/how-can-i-get-jquery-datatables-to-sort-on-hidden-value-but-search-on-displayed Working! SO rocks!