# Sort datatable by hidden column

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have `datatable` with `id, firstName, lastName, phone, updated` fields.

***Problem:***  I add to `datatable` only four fields (id, firstName, lastName and phone). `Updated` field is hidden.

***Question:*** how to sort `datatable` by `updated` field?

***My code:***

```
   $('#table').dataTable({
        sDom: '<"top"fi>tS',
        sScrollY: ($(window).height() - 250) + "px",
        bPaginate: false,
        bDeferRender: true,
        bAutoWidth: false,
        oLanguage: {
            sInfo: "Total: _TOTAL_ entities",
            sEmptyTable: "No pending entities"
        },
        "aoColumnDefs": [
            { "iDataSort": 4, "aTargets": [ 0 ] }
        ],
        "aoColumns": [
            { "sWidth": "10%" },
            { "sWidth": "40%" },
            { "sWidth": "30%" },
            { "sWidth": "20%" },
            { "sTitle": "updated ", "bVisible":false }
        ],
        fnCreatedRow: function( nRow, aData, iDataIndex ) {
            $(nRow).attr('id', aData[0]);
        }
    });

table.fnAddData([id, firstName, lastName, phone, updated]);
```

Comment: Do you want to sort it on table initilisation?

Comment: @dcodesmith yes. But it be good if I can sort it at any moment.

Comment: Ok, what position is the update column in your table, I know it's hidden but it should have index

Comment: @dcodesmith by hidden I mean that I don't add it at all. If I must add `updated` column, than show me how please

Comment: @dcodesmith I mean that at the moment `table` does not contain any `updated` field. I don't know how to add hidden field.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[From the documentation:](http://datatables.net/usage/columns#iDataSort).

> **iDataSort** The column index (starting from 0!) that you wish a sort to be performed upon when this column is selected for sorting. This can be used for sorting on hidden columns for example.
>
> `Default: -1` *Use automatically calculated column index*
>
> `Type: int`
>
> ```
> // Using aoColumnDefs
> $(document).ready( function() {
>   $('#example').dataTable( {
>     "aoColumnDefs": [
>       { "iDataSort": 1, "aTargets": [ 0 ] }
>     ]
>   } );
> } );
>  
> // Using aoColumns
> $(document).ready( function() {
>   $('#example').dataTable( {
>     "aoColumns": [
>       { "iDataSort": 1 },
>       null,
>       null,
>       null,
>       null
>     ]
>   } );
> } );
> ```

Comment: how to set sort order: desc, asc?

Comment: try this.."aaSorting": [[ 4, "desc" ]],

Comment: This is definitely deprecated now... you should be using `data-sort` via HTML 5.  Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/28730668/1408137

Answer (score 2):

you can simply use `{ "iDataSort": 4 }` here (4 is the index of your hidden field)

```
var data = [
["1","john","mathew","1234",[]],
["2","Mary","rose","1234","1"],
];
```

To add hidden fields and to add data to table

```
aaData: data,
aoColumns :[
        { "sTitle": "id","bSortable": false },
        { "sTitle": "firstName","bSortable": false, },
        { "sTitle": "lastName", "bSortable": false,},
        {"sTitle": "phone","bSortable": false},
        {"sTitle": "updated ", "bVisible":false },
        ]
```

To add hidden fields use `"bVisible":false`

Comment: how to add hidden field?

Comment: I'll check it in a hour

Comment: should I add `updated` parameter to datatable: `table.fnAddData([id, firstName, lastName, phone])` or `table.fnAddData([id, firstName, lastName, phone, updated])`?

Comment: ya! you have to add `updated` parameter like `table.fnAddData([id, firstName, lastName, phone, updated])`

Comment: I get `Datatables warning (table id = 'home-hr-candidates-pending'): Requested unknown parameter '4' from the data source for row 0`

Comment: add data to table like i have given in answer.. use two dimensional array to pass values to data table..

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a problem by sorting the hidden column in runtime, don't know the approach is valid or not. I used the following lines to hide the column via CSS

```
td:nth-of-type(2) {
display: none;
}
```

Where 2 is your column, assign a class to your `<th class="mycolum1">` and use jquery to sort it like

```
$("#button").click(function(){
$(".mycolumn").click();
})
```

Pardon me if the approach is not valid but in my case it is 100% acceptable.